# What does below error mean "AttributeError: 'Config' object has no attribute '_tmpdirhandler'"? Full error is given in the question body

Tags: python, logging, pytest

I was trying to use this Pytest logger  code https://pypi.org/project/pytest-logger/ . But I am getting below error. Please help what I or they are missing. What changes need to be made?

```
def logsdir(self):
        ldir = self._logsdir
        if ldir:
            return ldir
        logger_logsdir = self._config.getoption('logger_logsdir')
        if not logger_logsdir:
            logger_logsdir = self._config.getini('logger_logsdir')
        if not logger_logsdir:
            logger_logsdir = self._config.hook.pytest_logger_logsdir(config=self._config)
        if logger_logsdir:
            ldir = _make_logsdir_dir(logger_logsdir)
        else:
>           ldir = _make_logsdir_tmpdir(self._config._tmpdirhandler)
E           **AttributeError: 'Config' object has no attribute '_tmpdirhandler'**

..\venv\lib\site-packages\pytest_logger\plugin.py:81: AttributeError
```

Comment: show the code that _you_ called that caused this error

Comment: I am not able to add code due to character limitation. please see this url  https://pypi.org/project/pytest-logger/   I am using exactly same thing.

Comment: Pointing to the page of a pypi package does not answer the question what you did actually call. Please explain what you did do that caused this error.